# Separating application from logic and relative imports in python

Tags: python

I would like to have the following project's structure; logic is implemented in modules residing in `src` and an application residing in `apps`.

```
my_project/
├── apps
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── app.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    └── code.py
```

My objective is to be able to execute `app.py` from the command line (having `my_project` as the current directory).

Currently, what I do is to have the following in `app.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.')

from src import code
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--input', '-i', type=click.STRING)
def cli(input):
    print(code.my_func(input))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

I believe this is a non-pythonic solution. For example it violates [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id23). What is the right/pythonic way of including the module `code` inside the application `app`?

*Remark:* This is of course a very minimal example. You can find it as a minimal example [here](https://github.com/drorata/app-src-separated-example).

**Bonus** Even better, and ideally, I would like to be able to call `app.py` from anywhere and it will be able to find `code.py`. But I would like to have this without installing the project somehow.

Comment: One question, why not using a setup.py and let the modules get installed by `python setup.py install` and then they can easily find each other. I follow Clean Architecture in many of my projects and [this link](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2016/11/14/clean-architectures-in-python-a-step-by-step-example/#.WczCEhexVhE) can probably point to a good direction.

Comment: During the development, I don't want to run into the setup loop. I want to run the app from the project's root...

Comment: That is fine. In that case install it once using `pip install -e .` and this will create a symlink to your original project location so from next time onwards you do not need to bother. Just change files and use them. They should work

Comment: So `setup.py` should reside in `my_project` and it will install `my_project` as a package?

Comment: Precisely. I think this is a good option. I do it all the times, in production projects. It works very well. Bonus, you can host in Pypi (in private) if you want and then later pip install it anywhere you like. Makes the deployment easier using tools like Ansible.

Comment: @SRC In this case, I guess it would be better to rename `src` to `my_project`. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, recently I have replied to someone else on the similar kind of issue and with a bit more detailed. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525674/python-import-script-on-another-folder-in-same-level/46525924#46525924)
Please let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Just add the path to your project directory `my_project` to the `PYTHON_PATH`, and then all you need to do is import the src module as you would normally do.

```
import os
import sys

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../'))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_DIR)

from source import code
```

Remember, adding `.` to sys path is dangerous. Avoid it in all scenarios.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm doing. Thanks for the warning regarding `.`.

Comment: @Dror If your script is standalone, then you either have to hardcode the project directory into PYTHONPATH in bashrc, or you can do it at runtime. There's just no way around it. Projects like Django solves this problem by having a file that is always executed before any other code like manage.py and settings.py.

Comment: Similar to what `pytest` is doing?

Comment: @Dror exactly. Pytest does the same using `pytest.ini`