# Python import script on another folder in same level

Tags: python

Lets say this is my project structure :

```
codes

 - pre.py

training

 - model.py
```

Both folder have empty `__init__.py` inside them, and they are at the root folder of my project.

Suppose I want to call `pre.py` from the `model.py` :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../codes")
from pre import *
```

However the code above give me `ModuleNotFoundError`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You don't need to specify `.py` extension, try `from pre import *`

Comment: Actually you must not specify `.py` in import statement

Comment: well, using a setup.py at the outermost level and installing this as a package is IMO a better solution as this will help you to get rid of all the `sys.path` things and use the import directly as you are doing for all other packages.

Comment: Ups sorry the .py part is just a typo, my realcode dont use it (but still get the error regardless)

Comment: This issue with your code is that sys.path is relative to the current interpreter directory, not to the file being executed. So your code may only work if run from `training` directory.

Comment: I did some googling, tried a lot of ways but none of them working....what should I do?

Comment: Windows or unix?

Comment: Can you show how and where you call python ? or how you import model.py ?

Comment: @COLDSPEED why is this relevant ?

Comment: Because you use a relative path before your import and depending on where you call your pyfile from, that can be good or bad (mostly bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a setup.py file at the outermost level. So your directory tree may look like this

```
|_project_name
  |_codes
    |_pre.py
    |___init__.py
  |_training
    |_models.py
    |___init__.py
  |___init__.py
|_setup.py
```

Then in the setup.py do something like this

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

requires = [
    'six>=1.10.0',
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name="project-name",
        version="0.0.1",
        packages=find_packages(),
        author='Your Name',
        author_email='email@email.com',
        install_requires=requires,
        description='The API to fetch data from different sources',
        include_package_data=True,
    )
```

And finally from the outermost directory use `python setup.py install` it will install your package and then you will be able to easily do `from project_name.pre import *` in models

Also consider using a `virtualenv` for this kind of things.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Happy it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

try using full path of your code folder

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "fullpath")
from pre import *
```

Comment: I prefer relative path because I used 2 different OS

But yes its working using the full path. Thanks for the help :)