# Python3 relative imports failing in package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been reading tons of questions related to this matter but none of the has help me so far. I'm currently using the Python `click` library to execute scripts as commands.

The current command that I'm trying to execute is placed inside a Python Package which has a `__main__.py` file, like the parent dir has. The current project structure is the following one.

```
/myproject
   /foo_one
       __init__.py
       foo_one.py
    /foo_two
       __init__.py
       foo_two.py
    /foo_three
       __init__.py
       foo_three.py
    /foo_four
       __init__.py
       foo_four.py
    /foo_five
       __init__.py
       foo_five.py
    /foo_six
       __init__.py
       foo_six.py
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    foo_seven.py
```

Whenever I try to run the `__main__.py` script located in the project folder, the following error comes up.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.foo_two'; '__main__' is not a package`

However, if I try to execute that same script from a folder above with the `-m` option like this `python3 myproject -m`, the following is shown up.

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

The `__main__.py` has 2 imports like this... The `__init__.py` is empty.

```
from .foo_two.foo_two import AClass, AnotherClass, OtherClass
from .foo_three.foo_three import AnotherClassMore
```

**UPDATE**: Correcting the syntax error in a previous command, while calling `python -m myproject` gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError` because of a module that isn't my responsibility, which is basically a library that is used in the project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Module Between Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391421/importing-module-between-directories)

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62708809/2142994).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hopefully, this will be of value to someone out there - I went through half a dozen stackoverflow posts trying to figure out relative imports similar to whats posted above here. I set up everything as suggested but I was still hitting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module_name'`

Since I was just developing locally and playing around, I hadn't created/run a `setup.py` file. I also hadn't apparently set my `PYTHONPATH`.

I realized that when I ran my code as I had been when the tests were in the same directory as the module, I couldn't find my module:

```
$ python3 test/my_module/module_test.py                                                                                                               2.4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/my_module/module_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from my_module.module import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'
```

However, when I explicitly specified the path things started to work:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python3 test/my_module/module_test.py                                                                                                  2.4.0
...........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

So, in the event that anyone has tried a few suggestions, believes their code is structured correctly and still finds themselves in a similar situation as myself try either of the following if you don't just add your export the current directory to your PYTHONPATH:

1. Run your code and explicitly include the path like so:
   `$ PYTHONPATH=. python3 test/my_module/module_test.py`
2. To avoid calling `PYTHONPATH=.`, create a `setup.py` file with contents like the following and run `python setup.py development` to add packages to the path:

> ```
> # setup.py
> from setuptools import setup, find_packages
>
> setup(
>     name='sample',
>     packages=find_packages()
> )
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax would be

```
python -m myproject
```

This should execute `__main__` in the top-level package.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. If I execute the code like that an exception is thrown with respect to a module, but a module that is a library in the project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `__init__.py` in each sub folder with python code to tell the interpreter to treat the folder as a module

```
/myproject
   /foo_one
       __init__.py # add this
       foo_one.py
    /foo_two
       __init__.py # add this
       foo_two.py
    /foo_three
       __init__.py # add this
       foo_three.py
    /foo_four
       __init__.py # add this
       foo_four.py
    /foo_five
       __init__.py # add this
       foo_five.py
    /foo_six
       __init__.py # add this
       foo_six.py
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    foo_seven.py
```

the `__init__.py` is telling the interpreter to treat sub folders as python modules / packages and you should be able to import

The `__init__.py` file can be empty but needs to be present in the sub folders to be able to import that module / package

Comment: Completly forgot to add those as they're automatically included... I already have them, updated the question already. Sorry for that.