# Importing module from different folder using relative path and __init__.py files

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm on Windows 10, using Python 3.8.3.  Here is my simple folder structure:

```py
root_project_folder\
    __init__.py # Empty file

    project_1_folder\
        __init__.py # Empty file
        foo.py

    project_2_folder\
        __init__.py # Empty file
        bar.py
```

Within `foo.py` I have the following code:

```py
from ..project_2_folder.bar import Test

Test.test_method()
```

Within `bar.py` I have the following code:

```py
class Test:

    @staticmethod
    def test_method():
        print("Test successful")
```

When I run `foo.py`, I receive the following error:

```py
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I've read a few threads about importing using relative paths.  Here are the threads for reference:

[Python3 relative imports failing in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884390/python3-relative-imports-failing-in-package)

[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

[What is **init**.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

I did not append any directories to `sys.path`.  I also did not modify `PYTHONPATH` either, such as adding directories as an environment variable.  From what I have read, I don't need to do any of that. Would I have to add something to one of the `__init__.py` files?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are calling ```foo.py```? I'm not sure if you are allowed to go up a level from the script you called... if you call a script in your root that calls ```foo.py``` will it work?

Comment: Yeah I figured that.  I continued doing more research and it seems it won't work.  I even added the appropriate paths using `sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  I couldn't get it to work.